# Fatal error: Call to a member function getStore() on string

Tags: magento-1.9

I am kind of new to magento but I don't why am I getting the error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getStore() on string in /var/www/html/app/code/local/Webkul/Preorder/Helper/Data.php on line 641
```

after making the purchase.

Any suggestion why am I getting this error.

On line 641 in Data.php I have following code:

```
 $storeId = $order->getStore()->getId();
```

Comment: Anyone can guide me about the issue?

Comment: Please add some context to the exception, either module download page, or the place where $order is instantiated.

Comment: @Pranjal contact with  Webkul support team. They will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the order was not found. How about if you insert this code before the code `$storeId = $order->getStore()->getId();` :

```
if (!($order && $order->getId())) return ;
```

We had this issue before with `Webkul_Preorder` and we can't find any updated version of this module. So we did the patch.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look the getStore function what he return in this helper `app/code/local/Webkul/Preorder/Helper/Data.php`

```
Debug with :
Zend_Debug::dump($order->getData()); // look the value of store
Zend_Debug::dump($storeId = $order->getStore()->getId());
```